# Does this pointer casting break strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, c99, strict-aliasing

This is the fast inverse square root implementation from Quake III Arena:

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
        long i;
        float x2, y;
        const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

        x2 = number * 0.5F;
        y  = number;
        i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
        i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what?
        y  = * ( float * ) &i;
        y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//      y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

        return y;
}
```

I noticed that **long int** `i` takes the dereferenced value at the address (cast to a `long *`) of **float** `y`. The code then performs operations on `i` before storing the dereferenced value at the address (cast to a `float *`) of `i` into `y`.

Would this break the strict aliasing rule since `i` is not the same type as `y`?

I think that perhaps it doesn't since the value is dereferenced and *copied*; so the operations are performed on a copy rather than the original.

Comment: I think it certianly does, at least as long as `sizeof(long) != sizeof(float)`.

Comment: `sizeof` has nothing to do with whether it's an aliasing violation.

Comment: The code as written assumes `long` is a 32-bit value, just like a `float`.  The pointer casting seems dodgy, though I'm not sure if it's forbidden since the compiler can "see" what's going on [unlike a scenario where a pointer is stored someplace and then used later in a surprising fashion].  I think aliasing issues could be taken care of via intervening casts to `(unsigned char*)`, without code generation in cases which would have worked right anyway.  My own inclination might be to use a `union` instead.  Still not really portable, but compilers should expect unions to alias.

Comment: @supercat: The pointer conversions, and the dereferencings of the resulting pointers, are not defined by the C standard, per C 2011 (n1570) 6.3.2.3 7. An implementation may define the behavior. Converting through `unsigned char *` will not remedy this deficiency. (The pointer conversions alone, without dereferencing, are somewhat defined, provided the alignment is compatible, which is implementation-defined.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this code is badly broken and invokes undefined behavior. In particular, notice these two lines:

```
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
```

Since the object `*(long *)&y` has type `long`, the compiler is free to assume it cannot alias an object of type `float`; thus, the compiler could reorder these two operations with respect to one another.

To fix it, a union should be used.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it breaks aliasing rules.

In modern C, you can change `i = * (long *) &y;` to:

```
i = (union { float f; long l; }) {y} .l;
```

and `y = * (float *) &i;` to:

```
y = (union { long l; float f; }) {i} .f;
```

Provided you have guarantees that, in the C implementation being used, `long` and `float` have suitable sizes and representations, then the behavior is defined by the C standard: The bytes of the object of one type will be reinterpreted as the other type.

Comment: By the way, `long` is definitely the wrong type to use here. It should be `uint32_t`, or if you want to assume ILP32/LP64 models, `int` or `unsigned` would suffice. `long` is definitely broken on any real-world 64-bit target except Windows.

Comment: @R.: `long` being 64 bits violates the constraint “you have guarantees that, in the C implementation being used, `long` and `float` have suitable sizes and representations”.

Comment: I agree. I was commenting on the badness of the original code cited, not your answer. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it breaks aliasing rules.

The cleanest fix for things like `i  = * ( long * ) &y;` would be this:

```
  memcpy(&i, &y, sizeof(i)); // assuming sizeof(i) == sizeof(y)
```

It avoids issues with alignment and aliasing. And with optimization enabled, the call to `memcpy()` should normally be replaced with just a few instructions.

Just as any other method suggested, this approach does not fix any problems related to trap representations. On most platforms, however, there are no trap representations in integers and if you know your floating point format you can avoid floating point format trap representations, if there are any.

Comment: The problem with this is that Q_rsqrt is supposed to be a quick reciprocal square root so a call out to memcpy is undesirable.

Comment: @RunHolt Today's compilers have no problems inlining things like `memcpy()`. But I already mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Even if compilers can optimize the `memcpy` to a load and store instruction, I still think there's something backward about the idea that code which wants to do a simple operation must, to avoid having its functionality destroyed by the optimizer, request a more complicated (and harder to read in source code) operation and hope that the optimizer will turn that into code that's as good as what a non-optimizing compiler would have produced.

Comment: @supercat Well, you either play by the rules (of which some are questionable) or set your own rules if you can (e.g. gcc has some command-line options to help with bad aliasing (`-fno-strict-aliasing`) and other things). AFAIUI, unions do not guarantee (per the language standard) to work around aliasing problems, but in practice they work (as a common extension).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I thought later language standards did specify that if a union `foo` contains a `bar`, then a compiler will consider a write to a `foo` as being a write to a `bar`; I don't know if there are any compilers which didn't honor such expectation when it wasn't required and haven't been updated to do so.  Still, I can't help but think that the Standard should define something cleaner than memcpy, e.g. specifying that if a pointer to a `bar` is dereferenced and written to, it will be assumed to potentially overwrite things of type `bar`, *even if it's typecast before the dereference*.

Comment: Under such a rule, a compiler would have to accept that `*((int*)(float*)&foo)=someIntVar;` might overwrite any `int` or `float` whose address has been taken.  Such a syntax would IMHO not only be cleaner, but it would be friendlier toward optimizations than `memcpy(&foo,&someIntVar,4);`, since the latter would require a compiler to accept that any type of variable might get overwritten--not just `float` and `int`.

Comment: @supercat C99 lists in section J.1 "Unspecified behavior": `The value of a union member other than the last one stored into`. It also says (in section 6.7.2.1 "Structure and union specifiers", clause 14): `The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time.` Compilers of the past with poor optimization capabilities did not mess around with aliasing or unions. Modern gcc does mess around with aliasing because it can legally and is capable of exploiting it for optimization.

Comment: @supercat  memcpy() is a standard function known to the compiler and the compiler has every reason to expect that `memcpy(&someFloatVar, &someIntVar, 4);` overwrites only `someFloatVar`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: If `foo` is a global variable of type `long*`, would a compiler be entitled to assume that, following `float *fp = (float*)unknownFunction();`, a call to `memcpy(fp, &someFloat, sizeof (float));` will not modify the value of `*foo`?  By my understanding, it would be allowed to make such an assumption if the memcpy were replaced with `*fp=someFloat`, but a store to an unknown pointer via `memcpy` requires that any global variables must be flushed from registers, regardless of their type, since `memcpy` might legitimately modify them.  Am I in error?

Comment: @supercat Of course, if the compiler can't trace the pointer to the variable, it must assume that dereferencing said pointer either via assignment or via memcpy() can modify any variable. However, aliasing restrictions still apply to assignment, while they don't to memcpy(). Which means that with assignment you may get either more efficient code (aliasing is OK) or broken code (aliasing is violated).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: My point was that if there were a rule that indicated that `(float*)(int*)fp = someValue;` would be considered as writing to both `float` and `int`, then a compiler would only have to flush values of those types from registers, rather than having to flush pointers, `double` values, etc. as well.  Further, the double-cast syntax makes it clearer to anyone reading the code why a "normal" assignment wouldn't suffice (memcpy differs from normal assignment not just in how it handles aliasing, but also trap values, etc.)

Comment: @supercat I'd guess that the compiler would drop these redundant casts (if they are just that, redundant) and only consider the actual type of lvalue involved in the assignment (Btw, you can get a misaligned pointer from the pointer cast, which is UB). That's how I interpret `An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types` in section 6.5 "Expressions", clause 7. IOW, `*(type1*)(type2*)` is not an access type. `*(type1*)` is.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: The only stated reason given in the Rationale for having the aliasing rules was to make clear that compilers should not be forbidding from making optimizations that would be incorrect if things aliased, in the absence of evidence that they would do so, i.e. in cases where the possibility could be regarded as genuinely "dubious".  The Rationale recognizes that most reasonable applications would require that compilers behave usefully in more cases than required by the Standard, and that a compiler could be simultaneously conforming but useless.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: If compiler had been more interested in supporting existing code than in pronouncing it "broken", they could easily have recognized a few constructs in addition to those mandated by the Standard, thus allowing many optimizations that aren't possible with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, but while being compatible with many programs that would otherwise require use of that flag.

Answer (score 1):

`i  = * ( long * ) &y;`

This breaks aliasing rules and therefore invokes undefined behavior.

You are accessing object `y` with a type different than `float`,  or a signed / unsigned variant of `char`.

`y  = * ( float * ) &i;`

This statement above also breaks aliasing rules.